# Text over a video and a tinted screen in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

So here's the thing I am trying to do.

I have a **video/gif** which I want to put on my **bootstrap** site. I've also got a `**p**` tag which I want to show over the video and a tint screen so that my **paragraph** is visible.

```
<div id="headerwrap">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <video id="background" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" poster="http://i.imgur.com/TFjSLGK.png">
    <source src="http://sendvid.com/wdn96a4c" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">          
        <div class="tint">
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <h1>Test</h1>
     <h2>Make what people love.<br>
     </h2>
     <h2>This is testing the gif</h2><br><br>Learn More
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I also have got a screenshot of the video which will be initially present while the video loads and once video starts playing it goes below the video.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da6z0uch/1/) for the same.

PS: For some reason, the video isn't loading.

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem? Seems you figured it out?

Comment: Nope. If you see the tint screen, It is not of the same height of the image screenshot.

Comment: It is with me? http://i.imgur.com/FuF8aLq.png

Comment: So this is the screenshot. [here](http://sendvid.com/wdn96a4c) the video.

What I want is, image, over it the video and then the tint screen.

Tint screen so that I can see the texts.

hope the doubt is clear now

Comment: It's not. The problem you describe in your question is not reflected in the fiddle. Please set up a fiddle where the problem shows up, so we can fix it. Now it just seems to work and I see no reason to play with it, if it already works.